# Setting value of textbox by GetElementsByName

Tags: html, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I have a webbrowser control that navigates to: http://www.tinyurl.com/schoolbliz-login
and this is a part of the page source of the site:

```
  <tr>
      <td width="11%" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Username</td>
      <td width="41%" valign="bottom" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="text" name="user_id" class="textbox" onfocus="style.backgroundColor='#D3EBFF'" onblur="style.backgroundColor='white'"></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td height="25" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
      <td valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Password</td>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="password" name="password" class="textbox" onfocus="style.backgroundColor='#D3EBFF'" onblur="style.backgroundColor='white'"></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
```

I want to set the values of the textboxes(username and password) to a certain text. I have this line of code in my browser.navigated but it gives me an error:

```
browser.Document.GetElementsByName("user_id").SetAttribute("value", "usernametest")
browser.Document.GetElementsByName("password").SetAttribute("value", "passwordtest")
```

UPDATE 1:
I tried using HTMLElement but Visual Studio says it is not defined:

```
Dim elements As ArrayList = New ArrayList()

        For Each element As HTMLElement In browser.Document.GetElementsByName("id_number")
            elements.Add(element)
        Next
```

Comment: `GetElementsByName()` returns HTMLCollection. you have to loop through each elements and set values

Comment: im getting a not defined error when I try to create an array of HTMLCollection..

Answer (score 1):

`GetElementsByName` is plural and `returns an array`.

Either pick of the first return value `[0]` or give the text area an id and use `getElementById`

Comment: What kind of array specifically? when I try to create an array of HtmlCollection, visual studio says it's not defined..